# how to replace a div[ ] element with another div[ ] element?

Tags: perl, html, selenium

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
  my $v1 = $sel->get_text("//body[\@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/**div**/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div");

my $v2 = $sel->get_text("//body[@\id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/**div**/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div")

print ($v1 . $v2);
}
```

For every iteration, it has to find the 14th element starting from `div[10]` & replace it with the increased `div[ ]` element (Ex: if 14th element is `div`, replace it by `div[2]`. In the next iterartion find 14th element i.e., `div[2]` & replace it by `div[3]` & so on ).

By using PATTERN matching, it can't. Is there any method by using regex for finding that particular element & replacing it ? how can i do it ?

```
 my $a = "//body[\@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/**div**/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div"; 
    my @arr = split ('/' , $a); 
    print "@arr \n"; 
    my $size1 = @arr; 
    print "$size1\n"; 
    print $arr[16]; 
    foreach my $a2 (@arr) 
    { 
    print "$a2 \n"; 
    }
my $b = "//body[\@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/**div**/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div";
```

Two variables as mentioned in the above question as v1 & v2 (edited as $a and $b), the modification has to apply for both of them. I think i'm almost near to what you've told. Can yoy please help me further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use 5.010;
my $xpath = q(//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div);

for my $i (0..10) {
    my @nodes = split qr'/', $xpath;
    $nodes[16] .= "[$i]" unless 0 == $i;
    say join '/', @nodes;
}
```

Results:

```
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[8]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[9]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
//body[@id='ext-gen3']/div[10]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[10]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div
```

Answer (score -1):

Ummm, all elements are separated by **/**, right? So you can use the native split method to split the portion of the text following div[10] based on /. Store it in an array **$arr**. Merge it to find the length of the string, say **$len**. Find the index of the **div[10]**, say **$orig_index**. Then you find the 14th element, do a regex match to see which format it is in:

```
$arr[13] =~ /div([\d+])?/;
if ($1) {
  $arr[13] =~ /div[$1]/div[($1+1)]/e;
      }
else {
   $arr[13] = div[2];
   }
```

Now that the 14th element is changed, concatenate the array to get the new output string for the portion from the portion between div[10] and the 14th one:

```
{
local $" = ''; 
$newstring = "@arr";
}
splice($originalstring,$orig_index,$len,$newstring);
```

I think that will do.

Comment: @ Cupidvogel: what does $1 in if statement mean ?

Comment: Oh, you need to study Perl regex in detail. **$1** is the first group captured within parentheses while doing a successful match. So if the element is like **div[5]**, then $1 will be 5.

Comment: Please post the code properly formatted as an answer, the code you wrote is hardly legible.

Comment: @ Cupidvogel: Thank u very much for your suggestion. I edited my above question. please guide me.

Comment: I really don't see how you got near to what you want without using one line of my code. All you did was to split the string, and print out the number of elements in the split array, after which you printed out each splitted element.

Comment: @ Cupidvogel : Don't mistake me. I'm trying to analyse your code. Because i'm very new to perl.That's why i'm seeking your help in this. Please help me.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am asking, how did you get near to what you want without doing what I said? What I did was to find out the 14th element, check it, and update it accordingly, and then replace the old string by the new string. I didn't find you doing it, you just split it. So how come you got near?