# How to pass the xpath that is stored in variable?

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-rc, xpath

```
my $V1 = $sel->get_text("//body[\@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div");
print($V1 . "\n");
```

When i execute the above command, i could print the v1 without error.

My aim is to print the such values ( say around 20). But xpath for each variable varies by the `div` element only (i.e., `div` element preeceeding `table` should be replaced by `div[2],` and `div[2]` should be replaced by `div[3]` in every iteration.

Following snippet does the replacing div[] element. But saying as invalid xpath.

```
my $xpath = q(//body[\@id='ext-gen3']/div[14]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div);  
for my $i (0,2) 
{     
my @nodes = split qr'/', $xpath;     
$nodes[16] .= "[$i]" unless 0 == $i;     
#say join '/', @nodes; }
my @somenames = join('/',@nodes);
#print "\n";
#print @somenames ;
foreach my $val (@somenames) {
    chomp($val);
    #my @new_arr = $sel->get_text($val);
    print "\n";
    print $val; ***this prints the xpath value which i needed***
    my $V1 = $sel->get_text("$val"); ***#i'm passing the same xpath here within double quotes but says as invalid xpath***
     print($V1 . "\n");
    my @new_arr = $sel->get_text("$val");
  } 
}
```

Am i following wrong way of passing xpath ? How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare your definition of the XPath string [with mine in the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206978). You inserted a backslash in front of the commercial-at that does not belong.

Comment: @ Daxim : Even though if i remove that backslash, it prints the needed. But when i pass that value into get_text -> () , it says as invalid xpath. Another thing, after running a testcase in selenium IDE & exporting it in perl it appears with backslash.

Comment: even i compared both terms as if ($xpath eq $val) , it outputs as both are equal.